# Sharepoint Blog Comment Input textbox got disappeared

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, settings

I have one blog site created.I was working as required for almost 2 month.

But, suddenly comments link stopped working. I am not able to see Add Comment Textboxes.

There is no problem of security access,I have already checked those setting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to post.aspx
2. Find Webpart to add new comment
3. Right Click on it
4. Select webpart properties which is List Form View webpart
5. From wepart  Properties , Go to Layouts,and uncheck Close the webpart
6. Save the page (post.aspx)